# Why does my h1 text follow vertical page scroll when viewed from a link within LinkedIn on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, linkedin-api

I have a link on a LinkedIn page, but when you click this (on mobile), the text at the top follows the page down. This doesn't happen when viewed in browser. Just the LinkedIn mobile app. Is this anything to do with the url parameters (?utm_source=linkedin...) that are added? I've tried absolute positioning the text, but it acts like it's fixed. Any ideas? I've put a couple of simple pictures below to show what's happening

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the page or the code, this is pretty much unanswerable, the best we can do is guess.

Comment: i'd rather not send the link with tracking code. I just thought someone might have encountered similar issues with LinkedIn that could help. Guesses are welcomed! The css is fine on desktop/mobile. It's just the linkedin app where the text acts like it's fixed.

Comment: If it's just in that app, the only thing I can think of would be that perhaps the app injects it's own CSS that is colliding with yours. I'd try giving your h1 a more specific CSS selector in the stylesheet and see if that fixes things.